# Understanding Finally with Object Reference

Tags: .net, oop, object, coding-style, business-logic

This might be a duplicate question but i didnt get it on net. I have one function which return type is datatable.

```
Function a() returns datatable

Dim DtLocLiecence as datatable
try
--- in this part i get value in the datatable

--and i am now returning datatable 

return DtLocLiecence

catch ex

finally

DtLocLiecence = nothing
end try

end function
```

Now as we know datatable is a reference type that means 
object a   =1
object b
if we write b=a
then the reference of a got saved in b

so in this case when i am returning the datatable object and in finally if i write that datatable object= nothing then why  my returning datatable object didn't got nothing.
I am getting proper result but my question is if datatable object reference type then why my datatable not gets nothing in finally.

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you expect as return value and what did you get when you call this function?

Comment: i got proper result sir. i am just curious to know why my datatable not return me nothing even if i write =nothing in finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it some thought. When you do `DtLocLiecence = nothing`, you are nullifying `DtLocLiecence` and not the actual DataTable object. There is another reference to the actual DataTable that may not be as obvious, i.e. the function itself (through the `Return` statement), which keeps the DataTable from going out of the scope and thus being collected by the GC.

Comment: so that means in the return statement it doesnt return the object reference it returns only value of that object?

Comment: No, again the function is acting only as a reference to the actual memory object, just like `DtLocLiecence`. Think of it in terms of a pointer (if you have worked with C++). If there are two pointers a and b, both referencing the same memory object, and you set a to null, it doesn't wash out either the memory object or b. Reference variables are not strictly pointers (as in C++), but the basic concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because the value has already been returned when you set your local reference to null.  Perhaps thinking of it as follows might help you understand what's happening, in a hypothetical language where the return value of a function is specified in its argument list:

```
Function a(ReturnValue result as datatable) 
    Dim DtLocLiecence as datatable
    try
        --- in this part i get value in the datatable

        --and i am now returning datatable 

        result = DtLocLiecence
        return

    catch ex

    finally
        DtLocLiecence = nothing ' No effect on result
    end try


end function
```

Comment: so that means in the return statement it doesnt return the object reference it returns only value of that object?

Comment: @Terror.Blade - For a value type, it only returns the value.  For a reference type, it returns a reference.  DataTable is a reference type, so in the above pseudo-code, result and DtLocLiecence are both references to the same object.  Setting one of the references to Nothing / null doesn't affect the other reference.